# Insert a static row into json

Tags: json, awk, sed

I´ve a json which is a list of dictionaries with the next syntax:

```
 [ 
     {

    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 29, 2017 15:35:37",
    "Componente": "Bar",
    "IP_Origen": "175.11.13.6",
    "IP_Destino": "81.18.119.864",
    "Country": "Brazil",
    "Age": "3"

},

{

    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "IP_Origen": "176.11.13.6",
    "IP_Destino": "80.18.119.864",
    "Country": "France",
     'Id': '123456',
     'Car': 'Ferrari'

},
{
  "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Age": "1",
    "Country": "France",
     'Id': '123456',
     'Car': 'Ferrari'
},
{
    "Date_and_Time": "Mar 31, 2018 14:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "Country": "Germany",
     'Id': '2468',
     'Genre': 'Male'

}
]
```

And what I want to do is to create a new row in each dictionary with an static syntax. In fact, I want to insert it after the character '{'. So the expected output would be:

```
 [ 
     {
    "Title": "Example",
    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 29, 2017 15:35:37",
    "Componente": "Bar",
    "IP_Origen": "175.11.13.6",
    "IP_Destino": "81.18.119.864",
    "Country": "Brazil",
    "Age": "3"

},

{
    "Title": "Example",
    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "IP_Origen": "176.11.13.6",
    "IP_Destino": "80.18.119.864",
    "Country": "France",
     'Id': '123456',
     'Car': 'Ferrari'

},
{
  "Title": "Example",
  "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Age": "1",
    "Country": "France",
     'Id': '123456',
     'Car': 'Ferrari'
},
{
    "Title": "Example",
    "Date_and_Time": "Mar 31, 2018 14:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "Country": "Germany",
     'Id': '2468',
     'Genre': 'Male'

}
]
```

I have think about using sed and awk command but it is hard to me to insert in the first row.

Comment: Experts always advise to use tools like jq which understand the json well. Could you please do let us know if you have jq installed with you? Or you can install it, answers could be given by users as per that IMHO.

Comment: Yes, I have just installed

Comment: Why are you not using some programming language ? For me it looks as an easier option

Comment: And how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jq:

```
jq ' { "Title":"Example" } + .[]' file
```

Add the Title element to the beginning of each array.

To write the changes to the file:

```
jq ' { "Title":"Example" } + .[]' file > file.tmp && mv -f file.tmp file
```

Comment: But I want to rewrite the file

Comment: OK, I have added a solution to deal with that.